# React native app - Can't seem to wrap everything into . a container

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do I wrap the below code into an app-container please? I am trying to update from an older version of native.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator }  from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import SplashScreen from './screens/splash.screen';


const Splash = {
    screen: SplashScreen,
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        header: null
    }
}
const RouteConfig = {
    initialRoute: 'Splash'
}
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Splash: Splash
},RouteConfig)

export default AppNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```